# Unable to get request header in asp net core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a custom filter in asp net core web api which is as below but unable to get header info.

```
internal class BasicAuthFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private StringValues xyz;

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
  {
    var authHeader = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Basic", out xyz);           
  }
}
```

`TryGetValue` always return false however I can see `Headers` contains the "Basic" header. As I am new in ASP.NET Core so can anyone guide me what I am possibly doing wrong?

Here how headers looks like.
[image]

Comment: May be you should check "Basic" in keys, not in values?

Comment: @AleksejVasinov Thanks, You are right key should be "Authorization" not "Basic".

Comment: The left side is the key and the right side is the value.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Thank you all for your valuable input however below code worked as expected.

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
```

Comment: If you use C# 7, you can skip declaring the variable:  actionContext HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var unittId);

Comment: If checking for empty values consider that a `StringValues` object is returned, and, though it has implicit type conversion, it is required to use e.g. `if (authorization == StringValues.Empty)`

Answer (score 4):

```
public static class HttpRequestExtension
{
    public static string GetHeader(this HttpRequest request, string key)
    {
        return request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key).Value.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

calling method:

```
 var Authorization = Request.GetHeader("Authorization");
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? We shoule embrace the new variables. :)

```
bool tryGetValue = actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("data", out data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xyz = context.HttpContext.Request?.Headers["Basic"];
```

Comment: This is not correct. Header should be Authorization.